# sql query returning result from two queries with different priorities

Tags: sql, select, sqlite, coalesce

What I would like to achieve, in a single query, is to return the id of a record that matches a certain criterion, and if nothing is found, another criterion. So these two criteria have different priorities and a simple 'or' will not do.

I came up with two solutions but wonder whether this could be simplified:

```
select id,1 as n from <tablename> where <criterion1> 
  union select id,2 as n from <tablename> where <criterion2> 
  order by n asc limit 1;
```

or:

```
select coalesce ((select id from <tablename> where <criterion1>), 
                 (select id from <tablename> where <criterion2>));
```

What I'd prefer is not to have to repeat the communalities of the two queries (in reality I select more columns, so would have to maintain these in parallel), and both queries concern the same table.

In case there is a shortcut I'd be happy to learn about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one row, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
where <criterion1> or <criterion2>
order by (case when <criterion1> then 1 else 2 end)
limit 1;
```

Comment: Ok, this was the advantage that I don't need to duplicate the vars but I have to do so for the criterion. Seems I have to do one or the other.